# wxWidgets wxFile create file first round works, creating second round with overwrite flag fails with Access Denied

Tags: c++, windows, file, wxwidgets

I can't figure out why I keep getting 'Access Denied'.

I am using wxWidgets to create a file on Windows in the following directory: `C:\Users\username\Documents\MyApp`. Initially the file won't exist, and it gets created and all is well. Doing this a second or more time results in the error: `error 5: Access Denied`. This even happens when running the application as *administrator*...

The file in question is a backup of a sqlite3 database file and backup can be run multiple times in a day and thus can overwrite the previous file. The filename gets today's date appended to it.

Creation of the file is as follows:

```cpp
bool DatabaseBackup::CreateBackupFile(const wxString& fileName)
{
    wxFile file;
    bool success = file.Create(fileName, true, wxFile::read_write);
    if (!success) {
        pLogger->error("Failed to create file {0}", fileName.ToStdString());
    }
    file.Close();
    return success;
}
```

There is another function which appends the date as well as attaches the full path to the file name so the result is like so: `C:\Users\username\Documents\MyApp\myapp.2020-03-29.db`.

I have also tried checking if the file exists beforehand and using `wxRemoveFile(fileName)`, but this also results in the Access Denied error... Creating files in Notepad and Notepad++ works fine.

Am I missing something? I can't figure this out, especially since it creates the file the first time round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the 3rd parameter of `wxFile::Create(..., wxFile::read_write)`, so it can take the default `wxS_DEFAULT` value.

The 3rd parameter requires a value or combination of `wxPosixPermissions` enum type, *not* of `wxFile::OpenMode` enum type.

Comment: Thank you! It worked now, I misread the docs on `wxFile` and see now it should be `wxPosixPermissions`